# Azure Web App Profile UNKNOWN_ASYNC - What is it?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

My web app has quite a bit of a userload, but still - running on 10 azure instances it should run good.

Now and then some instances just seem to die, while others are still working perfectly. I tried to profile it through the Azure portal, but by far the biggest issue is something called `UNKNOWN_ASYNC`.

Locally I can't reproduce this problem.

[image]

- What could the reason be for UNKNOWN_ASYNC?
- How can I figure out what is going on?

Comment: It seems to duplicate with [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44117765/azure-slow-response-time-in-django-web-app).

Comment: Hi @NancyXiong-MSFT, the answer over there is talking specifically about Dangjo/Python. We are 100% on Microsoft/Azure stack.